# ui-calendar tooltip function not working

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, ui-calendar

calendar to display a calendar and set of events(events being hardcoded as of now).But when i hover on the event the tooltip is not displayed.I searched for many answers online and none worked for me ,Everything else except tooltip is working.Please help.Following is my js code

```html
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.calendar', 'ui.router']);
app.controller('myNgController', ['$scope', '$http', 'uiCalendarConfig', function($scope, $http, uiCalendarConfig) {

    $scope.SelectedEvent = null;
    var isFirstTime = true;

    $scope.events = [];
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
    $scope.events.push({
        title: "event",
        description: "jahsojoaisjjoijaso",
        start: new Date("2017-05-03"),
        end: new Date("2017-05-03"),
        allDay: false,
        stick: false
    });

    $scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar: {
            height: 450,
            editable: false,
            displayEventTime: false,
          
            header: {
                left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'today prev,next'
            },
            eventClick: function(event) {
                $scope.SelectedEvent = event;
            },
            eventAfterAllRender: function() {
                if ($scope.events.length > 0 && isFirstTime) {
                    //Focus first event
                    uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', $scope.events[0].start);
                    isFirstTime = false;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    
    
    
    $scope.eventRender = function( event, element, view ) { 
        element.attr({'tooltip': event.title,
                     'tooltip-append-to-body': true});
        $compile(element)($scope);
    };

}]);
```

and if i try the following code the whole event disappears.The event is no more displayed on the calender

```html
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.calendar', 'ui.router']);
app.controller('myNgController', ['$scope', '$http', 'uiCalendarConfig', function($scope, $http, uiCalendarConfig) {

    $scope.SelectedEvent = null;
    var isFirstTime = true;

    $scope.events = [];
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
    $scope.events.push({
        title: "event",
        description: "jahsojoaisjjoijaso",
        start: new Date("2017-05-03"),
        end: new Date("2017-05-03"),
        allDay: false,
        stick: false
    });

    $scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar: {
            height: 450,
            editable: false,
            displayEventTime: false,
          
            header: {
                left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'today prev,next'
            },
            eventClick: function(event) {
                $scope.SelectedEvent = event;
            },
            eventAfterAllRender: function() {
                if ($scope.events.length > 0 && isFirstTime) {
                    //Focus first event
                    uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', $scope.events[0].start);
                    isFirstTime = false;
                }
            },
            eventRender : function( event, element, view ) { 
                element.attr({'tooltip': event.title,
                             'tooltip-append-to-body': true});
                $compile(element)($scope);
            }
        }
    };

}]);
```

and the html code

```html
<h1> calendar</h1>
            <div ng-controller="myNgController">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                     <div id="calendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                     <div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top:50px" ng-controller="MyDbController">
                        <h2 style="margin-top:0px;text-align:center;" ng-repeat="elem in data"> {{elem.balance}}  Available  </h2>
                        <a ui-sref="apply" onclick="closeNav()" class="btn btn-success" role="button" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" >Reques(s)</a>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

updated code as per answer ..

```html
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.calendar', 'ui.router']);
app.controller('myNgController',['$scope', '$timeout', '$http', '$compile', 'uiCalendarConfig', function($scope, $timeout, $http, $compile, uiCalendarConfig){

    $scope.SelectedEvent = null;
    var isFirstTime = true;

    $scope.events = [];
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
    $scope.events.push({
        title: "event",
        description: "jahsojoaisjjoijaso",
        start: new Date("2017-05-03"),
        end: new Date("2017-05-03"),
        allDay: false,
        stick: false
    });

    $scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar: {
            height: 450,
            editable: false,
            displayEventTime: false,
          
            header: {
                left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'today prev,next'
            },
            eventClick: function(event) {
                $scope.SelectedEvent = event;
            },
            eventRender : function( event, element, view ) { 
                element.attr({'tooltip': event.title,
                             'tooltip-append-to-body': true});
                $compile(element)($scope);
            },
            eventAfterAllRender: function() {
                if ($scope.events.length > 0 && isFirstTime) {
                    //Focus first event
                 $timeout(function(){
                 uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', $scope.events[0].start);
                    isFirstTime = false;
                });
                }
            }
           
            
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set that function in the calendar configuration definition ([Reference](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)):

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar: {
        eventRender: $scope.eventRender,
        ... reset of the configuration
    }
}
```

Don't forget to inject `$compile` to your controller:

```
app.controller('myNgController', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', 'uiCalendarConfig', function($scope, $http, $compile, uiCalendarConfig) {
```

As for our discussion in the comments - You're getting *"TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullCalendar' of undefined"* error. Try the following

Inject `$timeout` to the controller:

```
app.controller('myNgController', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$http', '$compile', 'uiCalendarConfig', function($scope, $timeout, $http, $compile, uiCalendarConfig) {
```

And wrap this line with `$timeout`:

```
uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', $scope.events[0].start);
```

So the final result will be:

```
$timeout(function() {
    uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', $scope.events[0].start);
});
```

This will make sure that you call `fullCalendar` only after the view was finished rendering.

And for dessert - Take a look on how you set the tooltip:

```
element.attr({
    'tooltip': event.title,
    'tooltip-append-to-body': true
});
```

Note that it adds `tooltip="<title of event>` and `tooltip-append-to-body="true`, but in order to show the tooltip, you need to set a `title` attribute. Change it to:

```
element.attr({
    'title': event.title,
    'tooltip-append-to-body': true
});
```

I guess that you think it's Bootstrap.UI tooltip (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tooltip) so in that case you need to make the necessary changes to implement it correctly. But using `title` will ensure that while hovering over the event the browser will show you the default tooltip (Using the native HTML "title" attribute).

Comment: i have included all the dependencies

Comment: updated the question again.I think i have added the myCalendar part as well

Comment: @vikk See my updated answer, let me know if it helped

Comment: u mean to say just add $timeout(function() {
    uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', $scope.events[0].start);
});  after closing ui.config right ? that shows the type error twice

Comment: @vikk Yes, as described in the updated answer. I had a similar issue, so I looked at my code and saw that I solve it by wrapping it with `$timeout`, so  just make sure you're wrapping that line

Comment: the same line is there in the eventAfterAllRender function right ...should i delete it or keep both

Comment: @vikk Delete the line that is not inside `$timeout` - Basically you just need to add `$timeout(function() {` BEFORE this line, and `});` AFTER that line

Comment: updated the question with new code.That made the error go away ,but tooltip still not displayed

Comment: This answer works like a charm.But is it possible to use bootstrap tooltip.If i include ui.bootstrap in the module whole page disappears..anyway i am accepting the answer as at least default tooltip is displaying

Comment: @vikk Glad to help - About bootstrap, i'm not sure. Try figuring it out and post a new question if it doesn't work (Because as you said, it's out of the original question scope). You can comment here if you eventually opened a new question and i'll take a look and try to help there - Note that you now need `uib-tooltip` and not `tooltip` using bootstrap.ui

Comment: eventRender will execute more than once, so you should not put that in there